# C# listView check for repeated "fileName" entries

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

I am new to C#

I just want to ask if is it possible to check against a SUBItem in a listview for repeated values before i do a `ADD()` method??

Lets say i have a listview and i can add/delete items

I can have numerous items and subitems

I would like to perform a check before adding the file that i'm opening into the listview

The file that I'm going to put into would be, *name of a file*, eg **example.txt**

And if this file exists in the subitem, i will not add into the listview

Does anyone have any idea on how to check a subitem value against the value that I'm going to add into?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can iterate through the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items(v=VS.90).aspx) property of the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=VS.90).aspx), and then the [Subitems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem(v=VS.90).aspx) property for each item and finally check against the subitem's Text property.

The other option is to store the already added items in a List, and check if it already contains that item you want to add.

**Edit**: as requested, added sample code below.

```
private bool _CheckFileName(string fileName)
{
    foreach(ListViewItem item in this.myListView.Items)
    {
        // this is the code when all your subitems are file names - if an item contains only one subitem which is a filename,
        // then you can just against that subitem, which is better in terms of performance
        foreach(ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
        {
            // you might want to ignore the letter case
            if(String.Equals(fileName, subItem.Text))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

using(var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    // ... setup the dialog ...

    if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        // cancel
        return;
    }

    // note that FileOpenDialog.FileName will give you the absolute path of the file; if you want only the file name, you should use Path.GetFileName()
    if(!_CheckFileName(ofd.FileName))
    {
        // file already added
        return;
    }

    // we're cool...
}
```

I didn't test the code so it is possible that I have some typos, if so, please add a comment and I'll fix it (though perhaps it would be better if you tried to figure it out yourself first :)).

Comment: This is certainly the easiest option, but it's an O(n^2) solution which will run poorly with large datasets.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the guideline...but i wonder how do i do out the coding part...as in the checking part, please help

`foreach (listViewItem item in listView1.Items)`
 which will iterate through the Items property of the ListView

`{`
How to check against listview subitems when using openfiledialog before adding into listview?
`}`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper class that contains information about each item. For each `ListViewItem` you create a new instance of this class and set `ListViewItem.Tag` to this instance.

You'd only have to iterate over all the items, get the helper object for the item and compare with that helper object.